# Windows 8 C# Metro App - Image Save Fails on Second Save

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am having a problem saving an image in a Windows 8 C# Metro App. I have a canvas where a user can draw an image and save the image to a file.  I'm actually having a problem with the second save.  The first save completes without a problem.  If the user tries to save another image I get the following error.

**Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))**

Here is my code:

```
var g = Guid.NewGuid();

        myMerge = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(g.ToString() + ".png");

        using (IOutputStream ac = await myMerge.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
        {
            if (ac != null)
            {                    
                await _inkManager.SaveAsync(ac);                   
            }               

        }
```

The only way to save another image is to quit the app and start it again.  It seems like something isn't getting released but I'm not sure what.  The error occurs on

```
await _inkManager.SaveAsync(ac);
```

Thanks.

Comment: there is an [InkManager sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Ink-App-sample-61abaec3) but it's only in HTML/JavaScript. It looks like the same general flow though, with exception of an explicit call to ac.Close. That should be getting done via the "using" I'd think, but maybe worth a quick test to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: I did try using the ac.Dispose() instead of the using but I got the same result.  Unfortunately the error doesn't tell me much.